# Custom CellType in ComponentOne Spread for WPF

Tags: c#, wpf-controls, componentone, farpoint-spread

we're currently migrating a very old VB 6 application to .NET 4.5 WPF. This application uses the old Farpoint Spread 7.0 component. The old spreadsheet uses `CellTypeButton` extensively, but Spread for WTF doesn't provide this cell type. I also didn't find any sample code, tutorials, blogs on how to create a custom cell type for Spread in WPF.

Is it possible to create buttons in Spread for WPF? Has anyone done this before?
Any tips, resources or links to smaples or blogs on how to do this?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You may use **CustomFloatingObject**

The following code creates a floating object.

- Implement a custom CustomFloatingObject class.
- Create the floating object content.
- Add the floating object to the sheet.

Refer: http://helpcentral.componentone.com/NetHelp/SpreadWPF/webframe.html#floating.html

```
public class MyFloatingObject : GrapeCity.Windows.SpreadSheet.UI.CustomFloatingObject
    {
        public MyFloatingObject(string name, double x, double y, double width, double height)
            : base(name, x, y, width, height)
        {
        }

        public override FrameworkElement Content
        {
            get
            {
                Border border = new Border();

                StackPanel sp = new StackPanel();
                sp.Children.Add(new Button() { Content = "Button" });

                border.BorderThickness = new Thickness(1);
                border.BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
                border.Child = sp;
                return border;
            }
        }
    }
```

To add instance of this floating object into worksheet

```
MyFloatingObject mf = new MyFloatingObject("mf1", 10, 10, 200, 100);
gcSpreadSheet1.ActiveSheet.FloatingObjects.Add(mf);
```